# Blue Screen Error on installing Visual Studio 2015 - Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, bsod, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I want to install Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10. When the installation is complete, everything works perfect and good, BUT ...

...**when I reboot my laptop** (shutdown my laptop and then start it again) *I get a Blue Screen Of Death* that says *"**kmode exception not handled (`cng.sys`)**"*.

Then it restarts and Windows starts successfully (but slowly)!
I check my MiniDump Error and it says a **problem with "cng.sys" file**!

I don't have any idea about what is going on, and I can't find an answer anywhere, so I'm asking it here: does anyone have any idea about what can I do?

I tried *Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise* and *Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Enterprise*, but I got errors on both versions!
And for the record, I tried it on *Windows 10 Enterprise* and *Windows 10 PRO*

My laptop model is : Dell XPS L502x

Can anyone help me?

Comment: An BSOD connected to `cng.sys` normally indicates a memory problem.  You should run [MemTest86](http://www.memtest.org/) and verify your memory has no errors.

Comment: Be sure you run the DISM and SFC tools to repair any system integrity issues that you appear to have.

Answer (score 0):

[image]Not the cure, but a symptom treatment, disable fast startup. Go to *Control Panel*, *Power Options*, *Choose what the power buttons do*, Click *Change settings that are currently unavailable* and **uncheck** the *Turn on fast startup* option.

This prevents the bug in whatever driver is killing fast startup from triggering your CNG.SYS crash. Boots will be slower, but faster than the fast boot, crash, memory dump and slow boot that you're doing now.